# Variable used as iterator doesn't change its value within nested loops in Python

Tags: python, parsing, iterator, nested-loops

I have the following piece of code within my script and I'm using the variable `cubecnt` as iterator to parse through all the files I have. It should go from 0 to `parts_total`, but it doesn't seem to be working. How can I modify the code in order to have the iterator working properly?

```
parts_total = 5
rgx_start = re.compile(r'End of powder drop')  # Line just before the start of the layer code: "; End of powder drop"
for cubecnt in range(0, (parts_total + 1)):
    for layercnt in range(0, (layers_total + 1)):
        f_path = ("{}{}{}{}".format(f_folder, f_name, cubecnt, f_ext))  # Complete path of the part to be loaded
        if layercnt == 0:
            start_i = 0
        else:
            start_i = int(prev_start[cubecnt][layercnt - 1])
        with open(f_path, 'r') as gcodesep:  # Opening each file separately
            part_gcode = gcodesep.readlines()
            for i, line in enumerate(part_gcode[start_i + 1:]):  # Searching for the beginning of given layer
                if rgx_start.search(line):
                    if (cubecnt == 0):
                        layer_start = start_i + i + 1
                    else:
                        layer_start = start_i + i + 2 # Avoid the step down for the layer thickness twice
                    prev_start[cubecnt][layercnt] = layer_start
                    break
        layercnt =+ 1
    cubecnt =+ 1
```

Comment: And why do you think it doesn't increment? This is not a minimal reproducible example, so you need to provide more info

Comment: @JoanLaraGanau: converting a not answer ffrom a user that does not has enough reputation to comment in a true comment is a nice thing. When I do, I just try to give credit to the original poster, because I find it more fair...

Comment: The very last statement of your code, `cubecnt =+ 1`. What do you think that is supposed to do? If you think it increments `cubecnt`, it doesn't. And why would you want to anyway since the `for cubecnt in range ...` automatically does the incrementing for you? Try evaluating `x = 10; x =+ 1` and see what `x` is.

Answer (score 0):

The range function also has a 'step' argument, so maybe that's what you actually want to use. There is no point in using cubecnt =+ 1, as at the start of each iteration of the loop, cubecnt is given the value in the range object.